# NSDateFormatter and Region Format Weekday

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I got a problem with NSDateFormatter with different regions.

I'm retrieving a string from the database with the weekday.

```
//wdn is 0 for sunday //1 monday //2 ..
NSString *wd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",wdn];
```

then I'm formatting the string to have the weekday in letters:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"c"];
NSDate *d = [dateFormat dateFromString:wd];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"ccc"];
```

results:

```
//with UK region in settings //RIGHT
//0 SUN //1 MON //2 ..

//with US region in settings //WRONG
//0 MON //1 TUE //3..
```

How can I force to have the right result no matter which region I choose?

Comment: What kind of date do you expect to get when all you have is a day of the week? There's no date, there's no time. What is your actual goal here?

Comment: What I need to get is the localized name of the day (MON-SUN) starting from the day of the week number (0-6). I thought using NSDateFormatter could be a good solution to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to map 0 -> the locale's version of "Sun", you can use `-[NSDateFormatter shortWeekdaySymbols]`.

The documentation doesn't have any description of the ordering, but I've tried with en_US/he_IL for Sunday first and en_UK/fr_FR for Monday first.  In all cases the array returns the locale equivalent of `@[@"Sun", @"Mon", ...]` with Sunday being the first day.

Of course, your code may become invalid if you assume the locale is using a gregorian calendar, but that's really outside the scope of the question as that probably relates more to the design of the app as a whole.

Comment: [NSDateFormatter shortWeekdaySymbols] seems region independent so I think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString *)stringWithDayOfWeek:(NSUInteger)dayOfWeek length:(NSUInteger)length
{
    NSDictionary *days = @{
        @0: @"Monday",
        @1: @"Tuesday",
        // etc...
    };

    NSString *dayOfWeekStringRepresentation = days[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:dayOfWeek]];
    dayOfWeekStringRepresentation = [dayOfWeekStringRepresentation substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, length)];

    return dayOfWeekStringRepresentation;
}
```

Comment: None of this is needed. `NSDateFormatter` already has methods for getting weekday names and symbols and it is all properly localized.

Comment: Well, the question was about how to get the same result independently of region settings, no?

Comment: If the OP want the weekday names for a specific region then simply set the locale on the `NSDateFormatter`. There is no need to hardcode weekday names into an app.